# Your system is heavily damaged by Four virus!

Tags: virus

I'm using `Google Pixel XL` / `Android 8.1.0` w/ March 5, 2018 security patch level.

Yet, I've got following pop-up on my screen:

[image: 1]
[image: 2]

---

Per `Play Protect` - "Looks good" - No harmful apps found.

I understand one of way to go about it is to do `Factory Reset`, however is there another way which doesn't involve `Factory Reset`?

I'm not really sure, how this virus got on my phone at the first place as I don't install anything outside of Play Store, any ideas what can be done to avoid this in future?

Please advise.

Comment: There are no real Android viruses, these are simply malware or redirect issues. Even if there was, a webpage could not "detect" them. Wipe Chrome's cache, restart, and avoid the sites giving you this pop-up ad and do NOT under any circumstances download the "recommended" app or link on the page. See https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/190027/how-does-virus-been-detected-on-android-pop-up-on-chrome-when-visiting-some-si for more information

Answer (score 1):

It it **absolutely nothing** to worry. Feel at ease and close that shitting tab.

There's a special word, or terminology, for this kind of behavior of a random webpage, "scareware". Scaring pages frighten and threaten you by telling you that you're in danger, and try to make you download their promoted software (or even a *real* virus - though that's rare but that *does* happen from time to time).

Next time whenever you see something like this, close the tab with confidence. You're in no real danger. It's just a fake page.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen these windrows in the past. Not sure if its a virus or just a popup trying to get you to download one.

When it came up on mine, it came up simultaneously with a window I "DID" ask for. I closed the window with those messages, and moved to what I actually clicked on.